# How to get just that values that are not distinct (count > 1)

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, sql-server-2008

I'm trying (in SQL Server 2k8) to get a list of `TheField` where `TheField` exists more than once. Something like the following (except I know this isn't right):

```
SELECT TheField FROM TheTable WHERE COUNT(TheField) > 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`GROUP BY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) with [`HAVING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) clause:

```
SELECT TheField, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM TheTable 
GROUP BY TheField
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

> Specifies a search condition for a group or an aggregate. HAVING can
>   be used only with the SELECT statement. HAVING is typically used in a
>   GROUP BY clause. When GROUP BY is not used, HAVING behaves like a
>   WHERE clause.

Comment: Excellent. I'll accept as soon as it will let me (in 6 minutes)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`HAVING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx) clause:

```
SELECT TheField 
FROM TheTable 
GROUP BY TheField
HAVING COUNT(TheField) > 1
```

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'TheField' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @DontFretBrett: Add `GROUP BY TheField`, I forgot it in the initial code sample.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with Tim's since he included the count in the result set. I know I didn't ask for that explicitly but it is definitely helpful